# Associative array with wildcard in system verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, vlsi

Is it possible to iterate over an associative array with wildcard "*" using **foreach** loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) § 7.8.1 *Wildcard index type* states:

> Associative arrays that specify a wildcard index type shall not be
>   used in a foreach loop (see
>   12.7.3) or with an array manipulation method (see 7.12) that returns an index value or array of values.

Comment: The reason for this restriction is that the `foreach` construct needs to declare a local iterator variable, and that variable needs a type. The wildcard index is left over from the Vera language, which did not have the ability to declare an index type. Do not use wildcard indexes.